# Variable query parameter for MongoDB + NodeJS + ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

What I'm trying to do is pass a parameter into a get() method (I am currently using Express as my middleware). Right now, I'm able to pick up which color is passed, and see if it's undefined or not. However, it seems like the query doesn't seem to work.

The color is defined by an option that the user selects (in this case, a link). It seems to pass the parameter fine - it's just the query that I can't seem to figure out.

Here's the code that I'm using right now:

```
router.get('/cards/cardlist', function(req, res) {
    console.log('get /cardlist');

    var reqColor = req.query.color;
    var query = {};
    query[reqColor] = 1;

    var db = req.db;
    if(reqColor !== undefined) {

        db.collection('creaturecards').find(query).toArray(function (err, items) {
            res.json(items);
        });
    } else {
        db.collection('creaturecards').find().toArray(function (err, items) {
            res.json(items);
        });
    }
});
```

basically, if I manually add in (for example) red : 1, then it's able to pick up red just fine.

For reference, not every record will have a color saved to it. If the color isn't set, then I just don't have it in the record - that seemed to be the best setup for this particular project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do your documents have an attribute named 'color' whose value is set to the name of the color or do your documents have a key by the name of a color (like blue) whose value is set to 1? In short {color: 'blue'} or {'blue' : 1} ? Your query is searching for the latter.

Comment: Documents are set with color such as green: 1, red: 1, etc.

Comment: What is the query that you see in your MongoDB log or in your express log (if it logs)? Is the case of case mismatch or unwanted white space or some such small nuance?

Comment: Aha! I figured it out - when defining query, I didn't have the 1 wrapped as a string.

So basically, I needed `query[reqColor] = '1'`. Silly mistake, but lesson learned.

Comment: Indeed something to be aware of .. the MongoDB server doesn't do any type coercion so numeric values will not match strings.